# Php POST variable not accessible and not being written to JSON

Tags: php, json, post

Below is a rather long block of code (I've added comments). I have the situation where no data is written to the json file and variables are not being stored. I'm not sure where this error is being produced, so I give a streamlined version of the code.

Dummy data.

```
[{"datasetID":"5ff49f926666f","type":"","modified":"2021-01-07","language":"","license":"","datasetName":"","taxonID":"","scientificNameID":"","acceptedNameUsageID":"","parentNameUsageID":"","originalNameUsageID":"","nameAccordingToID":"","namePublishedInID":"","taxonConceptID":"","scientificName":"","acceptedNameUsage":"","parentNameUsage":"","originalNameUsage":"","nameAccordingTo":"","namePublishedIn":"","namePublishedInYear":"","higherClassification":"","kingdom":"","phylum":"","class":"","order":"","family":"","genus":"","subgenus":"","specificEpithet":"","infraspecificEpithet":"","taxonRank":"","verbatimTaxonRank":"","scientificNameAuthorship":"","vernacularName":"","nomenclaturalCode":"","taxonomicStatus":"","nomenclaturalStatus":"","taxonRemarks":"","commonName":"","elementName":"","commonElementName":"", "fileName":""}]
```

Code.

```
<body class="container" style="">
  <?php
  $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
  echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone;
  $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  echo "The current date time is: " . $datetime;
```

The `datasetID` comes from the url

```
  $datasetID = $_GET['datasetID'];
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("bonify" . $version . "/app/json/datastr.json"), True);
  echo $_GET['datasetID'];
```

Each record has a unique `datasetID` so the corresponding record is filtered out.

```
  function myfilter($row){
    return ($row['datasetID']== $_GET['datasetID']);
  }
  $result = array_filter($data, 'myfilter');
```

A foreach loop makes it easier to access the attributes of the json.

```
  foreach($result as $elem)  {
      echo(
      "
      <div class='sidebar-header'>
        <div class='user-info'>
          <span class='user-name'>
            <strong>".$elem['kingdom']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['phylum']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['class']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['order']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['family']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['genus']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['subgenus']."</strong>
            <strong>".$elem['elementName']."</strong>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

");}

?>
```

A form is set up to allow the editing of the values.

```
<form action='' method='post' class='was-validated'>
  <div class='row'>


<?php

foreach($result as $elem)  {
    echo(
    "
    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>Dataset ID:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='datasetID' placeholder=".$elem['datasetID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>Type: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='type' placeholder=".$elem['type'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>Modified: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' value = ".$datetime." name='modified' placeholder=".$elem['modified'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>Language: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='language' placeholder=".$elem['language'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>License: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='license' placeholder=".$elem['license'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>Dataset Name: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='datasetName' placeholder=".$elem['datasetName'].">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>taxonID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='taxonID' placeholder=".$elem['taxonID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>scientificNameID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='scientificNameID' placeholder=".$elem['scientificNameID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>acceptedNameUsageID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='acceptedNameUsageID' placeholder=".$elem['acceptedNameUsageID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>parentNameUsageID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='parentNameUsageID' placeholder=".$elem['parentNameUsageID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>originalNameUsageID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='originalNameUsageID' placeholder=".$elem['originalNameUsageID'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>nameAccordingToID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='nameAccordingToID' placeholder=".$elem['nameAccordingToID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>namePublishedInID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='namePublishedInID' placeholder=".$elem['namePublishedInID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>taxonConceptID: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='taxonConceptID' placeholder=".$elem['taxonConceptID'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>scientificName: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='scientificName' placeholder=".$elem['scientificName'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>acceptedNameUsage: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='acceptedNameUsage' placeholder=".$elem['acceptedNameUsage'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>parentNameUsage: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='parentNameUsage' placeholder=".$elem['parentNameUsage'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>originalNameUsage: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='originalNameUsage' placeholder=".$elem['originalNameUsage'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>nameAccordingTo: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='nameAccordingTo' placeholder=".$elem['nameAccordingTo'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>namePublishedIn: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='namePublishedIn' placeholder=".$elem['namePublishedIn'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>namePublishedInYear: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='namePublishedInYear' placeholder=".$elem['namePublishedInYear'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>higherClassification: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='higherClassification' placeholder=".$elem['higherClassification'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>kingdom: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='kingdom' placeholder=".$elem['kingdom'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>phylum: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='phylum' placeholder=".$elem['phylum'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>class: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='class' placeholder=".$elem['class'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>order: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='order' placeholder=".$elem['order'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>family: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='family' placeholder=".$elem['family'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>genus: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='genus' placeholder=".$elem['genus'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>subgenus: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='subgenus' placeholder=".$elem['subgenus'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>specificEpithet: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='specificEpithet' placeholder=".$elem['specificEpithet'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>infraspecificEpithet: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='infraspecificEpithet' placeholder=".$elem['infraspecificEpithet'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>taxonRank: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='taxonRank' placeholder=".$elem['taxonRank'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>verbatimTaxonRank: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='verbatimTaxonRank' placeholder=".$elem['verbatimTaxonRank'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>scientificNameAuthorship: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='scientificNameAuthorship' placeholder=".$elem['scientificNameAuthorship'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>vernacularName: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='vernacularName' placeholder=".$elem['vernacularName'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>nomenclaturalCode: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='nomenclaturalCode' placeholder=".$elem['nomenclaturalCode'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>taxonomicStatus: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='taxonomicStatus' placeholder=".$elem['taxonomicStatus'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>nomenclaturalStatus: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='nomenclaturalStatus' placeholder=".$elem['nomenclaturalStatus'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>taxonRemarks: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='taxonRemarks' placeholder=".$elem['taxonRemarks'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>commonName: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='commonName' placeholder=".$elem['commonName'].">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>elementName: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='elementName' placeholder=".$elem['elementName'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col-md-2'>
        <label>commonElementName: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='' name='commonElementName' placeholder=".$elem['commonElementName'].">
      </div>
    </div>

    ");}

?>
```

The data from the form is passed through a post method.

```
        <?php

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

          function get_data() {
            $datae = array();
            $datae[] = array(
            'datasetID' => $_POST['datasetID'],
            'type' => $_POST['type'],
            'modified' => $_POST['modified'],
            'language' => $_POST['language'],
            'license' => $_POST['license'],
            'datasetName' => $_POST['datasetName'],
            'taxonID' => $_POST['taxonID'],
            'scientificNameID' => $_POST['scientificNameID'],
            'acceptedNameUsageID' => $_POST['acceptedNameUsageID'],
            'parentNameUsageID' => $_POST['parentNameUsageID'],
            'originalNameUsageID' => $_POST['originalNameUsageID'],
            'nameAccordingToID' => $_POST['nameAccordingToID'],
            'namePublishedInID' => $_POST['namePublishedInID'],
            'taxonConceptID' => $_POST['taxonConceptID'],
            'scientificName' => $_POST['scientificName'],
            'acceptedNameUsage' => $_POST['acceptedNameUsage'],
            'parentNameUsage' => $_POST['parentNameUsage'],
            'originalNameUsage' => $_POST['originalNameUsage'],
            'nameAccordingTo' => $_POST['nameAccordingTo'],
            'namePublishedIn' => $_POST['namePublishedIn'],
            'namePublishedInYear' => $_POST['namePublishedInYear'],
            'higherClassification' => $_POST['higherClassification'],
            'kingdom' => $_POST['kingdom'],
            'phylum' => $_POST['phylum'],
            'class' => $_POST['class'],
            'order' => $_POST['order'],
            'family' => $_POST['family'],
            'genus' => $_POST['genus'],
            'subgenus' => $_POST['subgenus'],
            'specificEpithet' => $_POST['specificEpithet'],
            'infraspecificEpithet' => $_POST['infraspecificEpithet'],
            'taxonRank' => $_POST['taxonRank'],
            'verbatimTaxonRank' => $_POST['verbatimTaxonRank'],
            'scientificNameAuthorship' => $_POST['scientificNameAuthorship'],
            'vernacularName' => $_POST['vernacularName'],
            'nomenclaturalCode' => $_POST['nomenclaturalCode'],
            'taxonomicStatus' => $_POST['taxonomicStatus'],
            'nomenclaturalStatus' => $_POST['nomenclaturalStatus'],
            'taxonRemarks' => $_POST['taxonRemarks'],
            'commonName' => $_POST['commonName'],
            'elementName' => $_POST['elementName'],
            'fileName' => $_POST['fileName'],
            'commonElementName' => $_POST['commonElementName']
                );
                return json_encode($datae,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
              }
```

Some house keeping, directory structure created to store each record as a single json file in a heirachical structure - this makes sense in this case, accept that statement. So we check if the directories exist, if they don't they are made.

```
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."", 0777, true);
              }
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."", 0777, true);
              }
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."", 0777, true);
              }
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."", 0777, true);
              }
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."", 0777, true);
              }
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."", 0777, true);
              }
              if (!file_exists("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."/".$_POST['elementName']."")) {
                mkdir("bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."/".$_POST['elementName']."", 0777, true);
              }
```

Some variables are assigned

```
                $vernacularName = $_POST['vernacularName'];
                $elementName = $_POST['elementName'];
                $genus = $_POST['genus'];
                // $dataset_id = $_POST['datasetID'];
                $file_name =  $genus . '_'.$vernacularName.'_'.$datasetID.'__new2.json';

                if(file_put_contents(
```

The json file is created in the correct place.

```
"bonify".$version."/app/data/".$_POST['higherClassification']."/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."/".$_POST['elementName']."/$file_name", get_data())) {
                    echo $file_name .' file created';
                  }
                  else {
                    echo 'There is some error';
                  }
                }
                
                ?>

          </div>
```

Submit button and close form.

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Fortesting echo the variables, only `$version` and `datasetID` give a value, the rest throw errors.

```
<?php
echo "$version";
echo "";
echo "$vernacularName";
echo "$elementName";
echo "$genus";
echo "$file_name";
echo "";
echo "$datasetID";

?>
</body>
```

I'm trying to pinpoint the issue, any pointers appreciated.
The json file is created, but at the top of the heirarchy indicating the variables are not being accessed.

Comment: just one thing to note - when you create the directories ( or test to see if they exist and create if not ) if you start with the longest path first the hierarchy to that folder will be created rather than working from the bottom up as it were

Comment: Ah, so I could reduce it to a single if statement, I'll test that later.

Comment: There is no `fileName` property/value in the example JSON string yet the form has a field for that

Comment: added `'fileName' => $_POST['fileName'],` to the above code, an error when editing down the code, but it doesn't effect the main issue.

Comment: The `dummy data` you reference - is that within `app/json/datastr.json`?

Comment: there are 3 fields towards the bottom of the form with no `name` attribute - presumably the same as the variable assigned as placeholder. Also - the HTML in the FORM is invalid - you should have quotes around the values ( same holds true for the value for `modified` )

Comment: yes, the json is datastr.json

Comment: edited: removed the elements with no `name` element. The HTML in the form works and when submitted creates the json file.

Comment: so is that the issue solved or do you still have problems with this?

Comment: I found the issue, the `value` needed to be set rather than `placeholder`.